# invalid variable name in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default linux nginx server

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am try to rewrite url from nginx but the show nginx error log 
 > [emerg] 225048#225048: invalid variable name in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1276

```
server {
    root /var/www/mypath/2ndpaht/domain/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name domain_name.com;

    location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location = /index.php {
        rewrite index.php?id=$1 ^id-(.*)$ break; # error this line
    }
}
```

rewrite index.php?id=$1 ^id-(.*)$ break; line number 1276 
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the error, you need to change rewrite like this:

```
location = /index.php {
    rewrite ^/id-(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 last;
}
```